# Applying commits from another branch in between revert

Tags: git, github

I am working on my own feature branch (denoted with X) off production (denoted with Y). I had to revert back to a previous commit in my branch (X) but the problem is when I later merged into production (Y) it got rid of the changes in production between my revert commit and the original commit I reverted to.

Below is a illustration of what is happening:

```
Branches X and Y Together:

XA -> X1 -> Y1 -> X2 -> Y2 -> Y3 -> Y4 -> REVERT-TO-XA -> X3 -> Y5 -> MERGED-X-&-Y
```

I only wanted to undo the changes in X1 and X2. When I merged my branch (X) into production (Y) it also undid the changes done in the commits Y1, Y2, Y3, and Y4 which I want applied. How can I apply these commits back to production (properly) while ignoring X1 and X2?

**EDIT:**

the git log for my project is posted below. To clarify I want all the changes between

```
2d3183 : Revert back to b643690
...
... 
...
b643690 : ...
```

from all the other branches in the project applied except for the ones I have made to my branch (I want all changes applied except 646d17b b395349 e97c3e9 9dc258e a140b79). When I originally did the revert I didn't know it was going to revert all the changes that weren't from my branch as well.

```
 git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --graph --decorate --all  > log.log
...
...
...
| | | * | | | | | | | | | 020f2ff : ...
| | |/ / / / / / / / / /  
| | * | | | | | | | | |   5b471c1 : ...
| | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | * | | | | | | | | | | c20ec96 : ...
| | * | | | | | | | | | | 2d3183 : Revert back to b643690
| | * | | | | | | | | | | 646d17b : ...
| | * | | | | | | | | | | b395349 : ...
| | * | | | | | | | | | | e97c3e9 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | * a2b4928 :
| | | | | | | | | | | | | *   035a931 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |\  
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | | | |   d735a29 : ...
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| |_|_|/ / / / / / / / / / /  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | |   
| * | | | | | | | | | | | | aa9ed57 : ...
|/ / / / / / / / / / / / /  
* | | | | | | | | | | | |   16067be : ...
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/ / / /  
| |/| | | | | | | | | | |   
| * | | | | | | | | | | | c357737 : ...
* | | | | | | | | | | | | 18e3a8c : ...
* | | | | | | | | | | | |   3d0e4e5 : ...
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/ / /  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | |   
| * | | | | | | | | | | | 718ae8d : ...
| | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/ /  
| |/| | | | | | | | | |   
| * | | | | | | | | | | 940d7d7 : ...
| * | | | | | | | | | | 05ec501 : ...
| * | | | | | | | | | | 307e852 : ...
| * | | | | | | | | | | f5406af : ...
| * | | | | | | | | | |   2b63f35 : ...
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/ / /  
| |/| | | | | | | | | |   
| | * | | | | | | | | | 6eb2ee6 : ...
| | * | | | | | | | | | 1d22152 : ...
| | * | | | | | | | | | 79330ca : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | *   c74d4f1 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |\  
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | |   7590f30 : ...
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| |_|_|/ / / / / / / / /  
|/| | | | | | | | | | |   
| * | | | | | | | | | | 847089e : ...
| * | | | | | | | | | |   b5fab21 : ...
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| |/ / / / / / / / / / /  
|/| | | | | | | | | | |   
* | | | | | | | | | | |   2764d05 : ...
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| |_|/ / / / / / / / / /  
|/| | | | | | | | | / /   
| | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/ /    
| |/| | | | | | | | |     
| * | | | | | | | | | 7135d39 : ...
|/ / / / / / / / / /  
| * | | | | | | | |   34130b5 : ...
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | *   4e8333d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\  
| | | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
| | |/| | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | | | | | *   673ed39 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\  
| | | | | | | | | | * \   9747021 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | 3d29b61 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |/ /  
| | | | | | | | | | * | 0c7b411 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | 0123cc9 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * |   c14bea0 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \  
| | | | | | | | | | * \ \   98a7e48 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | cd40333 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |/ / /  
| | | | | | | | | | * | |   060cf5f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | * \ \ \   78aab2e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | * \ \ \ \   4663746 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \   60d9269 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | e73d473 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | a425dcf : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | |   af0af35 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | e20c304 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | |   16ec332 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | 0fc05ee : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | e3016b6 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | |   f95d358 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | 457ed41 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | bfbfd9f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | e54e821 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | f025bf7 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | 51323f3 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | 92da038 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | ebe897e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | a3f0a9d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | |   65c46c2 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | ffc219c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | e500648 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 3e5d9a8 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 4869aea : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 77fb987 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 60127ee : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 2cc13e3 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 0d95acb : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 1ac23e6 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 10f1861 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | 11f445e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | |   7ecfe60 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 7a02e11 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 7dd9d9c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 4799da6 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | c61ba2b : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 7a09a90 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | aea2e9c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 82788f4 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | e012181 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 80ab2af : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 3f1c5df : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | 7e8ec32 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | b3af270 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | c7185a3 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | |   1f4999a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | b41e309 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | b053e99 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 3df8261 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | a333444 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 29be6e8 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 805e493 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 659bf16 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | |   13a9582 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   50bfb28 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 462dc47 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | |   43a18ca : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | f2b22c8 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 75111ba : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | |_|/ / / / / / / / / / / /  
| | | | | | | | | | | |/| | | | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | 895b7c3 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | |/ / / / / / / / / / / /  
| | | | | | | | | | | |/| | | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 119e17c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |/ / / / / / / / / / / /  
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 350fbb5 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 7cd5315 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 16bb2dc : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 929e354 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 03ac90c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | d9db725 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 74f779a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 9195682 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | f27bb28 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 37471e6 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | f0effa4 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 41b427d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 96930dd : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | e3fbf4a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 5607dac : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 7bb1f62 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 86bb91f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 68c69a7 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 29a1bae : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 254e161 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | d5fde48 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | b61f781 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 556660d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 0a1ce6e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | aaf68c0 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 5abb897 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 447ae4a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 5f6ad0f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 80e6de6 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 42124b9 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | 2db14c2 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | fede81e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 6114c4e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | fd10284 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 5a88f3b : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 91bc5e9 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | e503b53 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 64395b7 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | bdc2b2f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 5f76b2f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | d4b382a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 470f88d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | eb03af0 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 251c782 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | f9c770e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | b700668 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 1822508 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 16ada5d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | d9ed953 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 10574f7 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | a1649a7 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 29791de : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 62a0d5b : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 0d29518 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 68eb493 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 1f03f64 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 95b6588 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | e5a2f86 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | ffc7474 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 31c8215 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | a29ed2e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 571cea8 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 4d05c21 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | c8c9733 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 073709d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | ad37783 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 73324b9 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | bd8890e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | f1c9593 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 7060c95 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | faa816f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 0876444 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 1bd7c26 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 1d5ed93 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 80df387 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 81c800c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 84d4679 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 2f67f85 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | f196e20 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 2e33c7d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 660f0df : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | c2c45d4 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | de3b2d0 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 4917e6b : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | f186e09 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 062d560 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 744dac5 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | e2a2322 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 39f4f5a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 55c32ac : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 774e020 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 3500f26 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 8d47e2f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 3a928a5 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 1f44d2a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | e267c49 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 96e554c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 4d109a1 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | c2c18f6 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 118a672 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 0636c0e : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | c2d2694 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 1244e82 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | b98bf3b : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 08db010 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 4bfdb60 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 953267a : ...
| | | | | | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | 453ae8f : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | |_|_|_|_|/ / / / / / /  
| | | | | | | | | | |/| | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * bded36b : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * ef3a3b0 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 23e5e6c : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 432c796 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 7b13390 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * c2d1332 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | *   288bc57 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\  
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 5197219 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * | 85350cf : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |/  
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * c4f46fd : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * aef138d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 0555803 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 9389d17 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 41fa707 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * e87d007 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | *   d5bdf0d : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\  
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 7baf406 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * d67dbb7 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 0879bd2 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * daac0b3 : ...
| | | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
| | |/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 33a96d4 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 15d075b : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * d09f785 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 73022f4 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 57dbe35 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 0bd6d55 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 28dbc40 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 5d38dd4 : ...
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * e4ec95a : ...
| | | | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
| | | |/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 2fb6b97 : ...
| | | | | | |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/  
| | | | | |/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   a140b79 : ...
| | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | |/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /  
| | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   23f01e8 : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   6b91193 : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | |_|_|_|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /  
| | |/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   
| | | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   5442f89 : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   74362a2 : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   339f831 : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   7f3a8ad : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   0bb0f3c : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   d63cede : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | | * \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   9a3e82e : ...
| | | | | | |\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| | | | | * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | b643690 : ... 
...
...
...
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you really revert the commit, or did you use `git reset` to go back to XA?

Comment: @AntoinePietri I believe I reverted. When I click my revert commit I see a bunch of changes I didn't want to happen and didn't realize at the time.

Comment: I'm slightly unclear what the current state of your repository is. If possible/willing, can you try `git log --pretty=format:"%h" --graph --decorate` on your repository, copy and paste the result into your question, and use the result to re-explain what you want to do? If you want a more informative log you can also try `git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph --decorate`.

Comment: I would suggest adding `--all` to this command.

Comment: @kshikama added your request

Comment: @AntoinePietri added your request